# How do I make an image link tag using haml in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have something like this in application.html.haml:

```
#header
    = image_tag("header.jpg")
```

How do I make that link to www.google.com, for example?

Thanks

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I do it this way:

```
= link_to image_tag( 'header.jpg'), 'http://www.google.com'
```

Comment: that works, thank you.  do you know how i can remove the image border?  set style stuff in the helper?

Comment: Just remove it with CSS, if you use SASS:

    #header
      a
        img
          :border-style none

Comment: hi, how do you add an alt tag and class to the image also?