# How to add an image to the contents using HAML?

Tags: image, haml

New to this tagging language, and I'm having trouble finding documentation mentioning how to work with images. An example or two would be fantastic.

Btw, I did refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202654/how-do-i-make-an-image-link-tag-using-haml-in-rails), but not sure if that's what I need.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Outside any kind of framework:

```
%img(src="/images/loading.gif")
```

The older, more verbose but flexible syntax:

```
%img{:src => "/images/loading.gif"}
```

If you’re using Rails, it will generate the tag itself:

```
=image_tag "loading.gif"
```

Comment: Thanks Buck! How would this change if I want to add more attributes to the img? (a data attr for example)

Comment: You can use the same syntax as the `src` attribute, that generic approach works: `%img{:src => "whatever.gif", :data => "something"}`